# SSMS SQL Row_Number incorrect sort

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to sort by USID and then Date and restart the row number on USID, Utilized. But for some reason the Date is in the incorrect order, so the row numbering isn't doing what I need.

Currently this is what my code is getting me:

```
USID | Date   | Utilized | RowNumber
123  | 1/1/19 | T        | 1
123  | 1/2/19 | T        | 2
123  | 1/3/19 | T        | 3
123  | 1/19/19| T        | 4
123  | 1/20/19| T        | 5
123  | 1/21/19| T        | 6
123  | 1/4/19 | F        | 1
123  | 1/5/19 | F        | 2
123  | 1/6/19 | F        | 3
123  | 1/7/19 | F        | 4
123  | 1/8/19 | F        | 5
123  | 1/9/19 | F        | 6
125  | 1/1/19 | T        | 1
125  | 1/2/19 | T        | 2
125  | 1/3/19 | T        | 3
125  | 1/10/19| T        | 4
125  | 1/11/19| T        | 5
125  | 1/12/19| T        | 6
125  | 1/4/19 | F        | 1
125  | 1/5/19 | F        | 2
125  | 1/6/19 | F        | 3
125  | 1/7/19 | F        | 4
125  | 1/8/19 | F        | 5
125  | 1/9/19 | F        | 6
```

However I would want it to look like:

```
USID | Date   | Utilized | RowNumber
123  | 1/1/19 | T        | 1
123  | 1/2/19 | T        | 2
123  | 1/3/19 | T        | 3
123  | 1/4/19 | F        | 1
123  | 1/5/19 | F        | 2
123  | 1/6/19 | F        | 3
123  | 1/7/19 | F        | 4
123  | 1/8/19 | F        | 5
123  | 1/9/19 | F        | 6
123  | 1/19/19| T        | 1
123  | 1/20/19| T        | 2
123  | 1/21/19| T        | 3
125  | 1/1/19 | T        | 1
125  | 1/2/19 | T        | 2
125  | 1/3/19 | T        | 3
125  | 1/4/19 | F        | 1
125  | 1/5/19 | F        | 2
125  | 1/6/19 | F        | 3
125  | 1/7/19 | F        | 4
125  | 1/8/19 | F        | 5
125  | 1/9/19 | F        | 6
125  | 1/10/19| T        | 1
125  | 1/11/19| T        | 2
125  | 1/12/19| T        | 3
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
select 
   USID, cast(Date as datetime) as Date, Utilized, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USID, Utilized 
                       ORDER BY USID, cast(Date as datetime) ASC, Utilized)
from vps_time_FullyUtilized
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It appears you want to count withing clusters of group values and restart the count when the cluster changes value.

Comment: What's the point of `cast(Date as datetime) `? Dates don't need casting. They aren't displayed using two-digit years either. If you store dates as strings, even worse, as two-digit years, you have a major bug. In the very year that Lloyds and UBS crashed due to such Y2K hacks

Comment: BTW by storing strings instead of dates you're actually using more storage. The `date` type takes just 3 bytes. Fix the table schema. PS SSMS is just a client tool, not the database server. It doesn't affect how the server sorts

Comment: They are being stored as dates in the source system but in order to get two tables to jive for this view they're mapping in as varchar. In this context I really just need to figure out how to get the sorting correct

Comment: @TAD then "they" should fix the bug, because that breaks sorting too. And the Y2K bug

Comment: You can't solve this just by using `ROW_NUMBER`. You need to find the "islands" with the same USID and Utilized values. The actual name of this problem is `gaps and islands`. You can use the `LEAD` or `LAG` functions to find the next `Utilized` value in a result set and detect when an island finishes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the dates are coming through correctly when I run the view, I shortened and changed the dates above for security reasons: 2020-01-28 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one gaps and islands solution.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53af2b/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T(USID INT, Date DATETIME, Utilized NVARCHAR(10))
    INSERT INTO T VALUES
    (123,  '1/1/19',  'T'),
    (123,  '1/2/19',  'T'),
    (123,  '1/3/19',  'T'),
    (123,  '1/4/19',  'F'),
    (123,  '1/5/19',  'F'),
    (123,  '1/6/19',  'F'),
    (123,  '1/7/19',  'F'),
    (123,  '1/8/19',  'F'),
    (123,  '1/9/19',  'F'),
    (123,  '1/19/19', 'T'),
    (123,  '1/20/19', 'T'),
    (123,  '1/21/19', 'T'),
    
    (223,  '1/1/19',  'T'),
    (223,  '1/2/19',  'T'),
    (223,  '1/3/19',  'T'),
    (223,  '1/4/19',  'F'),
    (223,  '1/5/19',  'F'),
    (223,  '1/6/19',  'F'),
    (223,  '1/7/19',  'F'),
    (223,  '1/8/19',  'F'),
    (223,  '1/9/19',  'F'),
    (223,  '1/19/19', 'T'),
    (223,  '1/20/19', 'T'),
    (223,  '1/21/19', 'T')
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH DataWithEndBoundries AS
(
    SELECT 
        USID,Date,Utilized,
        --Mark your groups here
        IsNewGroup = CASE WHEN ISNULL(LAG(Utilized) OVER (ORDER BY USID,Date),Utilized)<>Utilized THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM 
        T
)
,VirtualGroup AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        --This serialzes the marked groups into clusters 
        VirtualGroupID = SUM(IsNewGroup) OVER (ORDER BY USID, Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM 
        DataWithEndBoundries
)
SELECT 
    USID, Date, Utilized,
    --Now you can row number agianst the Virtualized value
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USID, VirtualGroupID ORDER BY Date)
FROM 
    VirtualGroup
ORDER BY 
    USID,Date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53af2b/4/0)**:

```
| USID |                 Date | Utilized | RowNumber |
|------|----------------------|----------|-----------|
|  123 | 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z |        T |         1 |
|  123 | 2019-01-02T00:00:00Z |        T |         2 |
|  123 | 2019-01-03T00:00:00Z |        T |         3 |
|  123 | 2019-01-04T00:00:00Z |        F |         1 |
|  123 | 2019-01-05T00:00:00Z |        F |         2 |
|  123 | 2019-01-06T00:00:00Z |        F |         3 |
|  123 | 2019-01-07T00:00:00Z |        F |         4 |
|  123 | 2019-01-08T00:00:00Z |        F |         5 |
|  123 | 2019-01-09T00:00:00Z |        F |         6 |
|  123 | 2019-01-19T00:00:00Z |        T |         1 |
|  123 | 2019-01-20T00:00:00Z |        T |         2 |
|  123 | 2019-01-21T00:00:00Z |        T |         3 |
|  223 | 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z |        T |         1 |
|  223 | 2019-01-02T00:00:00Z |        T |         2 |
|  223 | 2019-01-03T00:00:00Z |        T |         3 |
|  223 | 2019-01-04T00:00:00Z |        F |         1 |
|  223 | 2019-01-05T00:00:00Z |        F |         2 |
|  223 | 2019-01-06T00:00:00Z |        F |         3 |
|  223 | 2019-01-07T00:00:00Z |        F |         4 |
|  223 | 2019-01-08T00:00:00Z |        F |         5 |
|  223 | 2019-01-09T00:00:00Z |        F |         6 |
|  223 | 2019-01-19T00:00:00Z |        T |         1 |
|  223 | 2019-01-20T00:00:00Z |        T |         2 |
|  223 | 2019-01-21T00:00:00Z |        T |         3 |
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there are more USIDs then just the one. I also cant use the Order by since I need to put this into a view so that I can push the data to another tool. I was able to solve the date issue, so that shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: I added USID to the LAG to pick up on multiple USID values.

Comment: As far as the view goes simply order after you select from the view -> SELECT * FROM MyView ORDER BY USID,Date

Comment: In my result I'm not getting the correct result: USID Date Utilized RowNumber
155 9/28/2020 F 1
155 9/29/2020 F 2
155 9/30/2020 F 3
155 10/1/2020 F 4
155 10/2/2020 F 1
155 10/5/2020 F 1
155 10/6/2020 F 2
155 10/7/2020 F 3
155 10/8/2020 F 1

Comment: For instance with your result if you look at row 17, it restarts for some reason as a 1 again: 223 2019-01-05 00:00:00.000 F 1. Same with row 23, the second to last row

Comment: Tweaked it to include USID in VirtualGroupID .